# Error using Android textviews in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with this part of a switch statement, but I'm stumped, and I just need someone to have a look over it.

```
switch(buttonId)
        {
  /* LOTS OF CASES HERE */
  default:
  case R.id.goButton:
        TextView rootNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.otherView);
        String rootDone = rootNum.getText().toString();
        it = Integer.parseInt(rootDone);
      break;
  }
```

Can you see anything wrong?

**Update**

Sorry about not posting the log, I though the problem would be obvious but it seems not so.

These are the two logcat errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method RootMe(View) in the activity class root.me.RootMeActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'goButton'

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: RootMe [class android.view.View]
```

Comment: can you let us know the error you are getting?

Comment: It should work if the otherview in in the main layout which your using. check it and if it is not working add more clarification to your question.

Comment: Do you get any exception or error?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting from the logcat?

Comment: @VictorWong it works in both orders

Comment: @WarrentFaith, haha, you're right. Silly mistake.

Comment: Solved as per my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it myself.

It was a typo, I mistyped the name of the method to be called onclick in the XML.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in xml you have mentioned the onclick event of goButton to call RootMe method `(android:onClick="RootMe")` but you have not defined that method in your activity. 
***SO delete `android:onClick="RootMe"`from your XML and assign onClickListener to that button inside the activity***

**Sample Code**

**XML**

```
<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Button1"
android:id="@+id/btn1" />


<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button2"
android:id="@+id/btn2" />
```

**SourceCode**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = arg0.getId();
        System.out.println("....clicked id..."+id);
        System.out.println("....id of btn1.."+R.id.btn1);
        System.out.println("....id of btn2.."+R.id.btn2);
        switch(id){
        case R.id.btn1:
            Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "....."+1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            Toast.makeText(ExampleActivity.this, "....."+2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, but as per my answer below, I have fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Write key word "break" after default.

Comment: The point is that default gives the same as the case I gave.

Comment: I think you have written your button's onClick="RootMe()" in your layout.xml file. But not defined in java file.